# AppFabric using more and more memory

Tags: caching, appfabric

We are using AppFabric 1.1 for caching in a multi services application.
The base functionalities works just fine but now we're fine tuning and we stumble across some memory issues.
We saw that AppFabric is using more and more memory as time goes by, yet we're supposed to have a finite  volume of stored objects.
I spent some time reading online and checking my code but I couldn't find why. So before engaging in war against "memory leak", I mean storage of un-referenced data or not referenced anymore, I'd like to know if this is a standard behavior in AppFabric ?

Could the massive use of GetLock-PutUnlock and massive readings and writings could cause the memory to go up to the limit allowed for the cache cluster ?

We used different size limits (1024 - 1536 - 2048) and different watermarks but it still goes up to either the maximum size limit or High watermark (we tried 75, 80 and 90).

If you need anymore information please tell me.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

we decided that we had to abandon AppFabric as there seems to be no valid work-around for this issue. Instead we'll use a Windows Azure hosted Redis cache. Hopefully there will be everything we need in Redis.

If a fix or a solution is known I'd still like to know of it, if anyone has it.
Thanks.

Comment: "massive use" of "massive readings and writings" in an in-memory cache will inevitably result in increased memory usage. Is the cache using more memory than configured, in which case can you show your cluster config?

Comment: I found my answer but I'm not pleased. from [here](http://sndshreeman.wordpress.com/2010/10/08/app-fabric-caching-templatebest-practices-and-useful-links/)
 I found 
 "Expiration time on Velocity should not be set to very 
 small values, which lead to increasing memory consumption, not decreasing. This occurs because of delays of garbage collection calls―old data expires, but remains in memory, and a new copy of data is added to memory."

Comment: out of interest, what's your expiration time set to?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. we can't use expiration in our case because data the cache is used as a super-fast db and thus data could be valid for 10 seconds or 10 days. We have a layer that manages that pretty well. By default we use Timespan.Maxvalue, to be sure we don't loose data. The point is, fetching data in db would be very time consuming and we can't afford it there.